# Compatible filter for a Hiyasu HR-24LA HVAC unit?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, filter

We bought a house with the A/C installed. We found a lot of dust, and realized that the filter was entirerly missing in the indoor unit. I have found it in the Hiyasu catalog, and I found a manual for it. The latter states that the filter should be cleaned, but does not mention any part number, model or type for the filter if it needs replacing. To make matters worse, the hatch for access to the unit is badly placed, and I can barely reach where the filter is supposed to be, let alone get a good look at it. I found a schematic for it here: https://tienda.splitmania.com/productpartsdiagram/index/viewparts/id/22630/ (in Spanish), but it also does not mention the filter. Does anybody know what type of filter I should get for this unit?

Just some further info: I stuck my head up there again to measure it, and also take a video. There appears to be a metal frame of 102 x 23 x 4 cm where I could place a filter. So what I can do is buy a roll of filter material with a thickness of 4cm, then cut a piece of 102x23cm and then push it in there? The metal frame doesn't have an inside edge, and I can't reach the far end, so I am not sure how I get the filter in without leaving a gap at the far end. Maybe I should build a plastic frame for it that I can put the filter in and then fit it over the front?

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9ioptUIdvc

Comment: I usually put filters prior to the furnace / air handler measure the height of the opening, measure the depth now this should be within a 1/2” of the square size and the width. I really only use 1” and 4” thick filters. If the filter is on the duct any physical sizes the furnace calls out may not be correct for the setup. However if a MERV # is given do not go above this value as it will affect the flow.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have edited the question with some further info, as I can't find anything from the official dealer, so I will have to craft some solution myself.

Comment: So you have a small twin blower, these usually have a grid that the filter is placed on (or the ones I have serviced do) I purchase filter media by the roll I do not clean it I think a 3’ wide roll I buy in 125’ rolls merv 7 or 8 and it cost about a dollar a foot for polyester I know there are smaller rolls available but I use a large amount and it is easy to cut with a razor knife. I have tried fiberglass way messy I don’t recommend and pleated filters need a frame. 
Hope that helps.